# IntelliJ not showing 'Test Module' option for Android

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I'm attempting to add a test module to my existing Android application using IntelliJ, however  the option does not show up in the list of available Android modules.

If I create a new Android project from scratch in IntelliJ it gives me no option to add testing, and again there is no ability to add a test module.

Are there any prerequisites, or some other reason why this isn't working for me?  There are no errors in the log that I can see that is related to either testing or Android.

I'm using Intellij 13.1.1 with Android Support 10.0.  The JUnit and TestNG plugins are active.

Answer (score 1):

The gradle build system for Android does not require a separate test module.  The information available at [the Android site](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Testing) explains how to set up testing in this environment.

If you obtain any errors regarding tasks being unavailable then please be sure to run `gradle tasks` to see which tasks are available.  In my case although the document referred to tasks such as `assembleTest` this did not exist in my build and instead I had to use `assembleDebugTest`, for example.